# How do I initiate Undetected ChromeDriver in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I have a project using regular ChromeDriver and this is how I initiate it:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, option);
```

Now I need to switch to using the Undected ChromeDriver. I installed it using the NuGet Manager and added the using to my project:

```
using Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver;
```

Now I have to initiate the new driver in order to work. How do I do that?

This is where I found the Undetected ChromeDriver:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver

Answer (score 0):

```
using Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver;

var webBrowser = Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver.Instance(false);
webBrowser.GoTo("https://google.com");
```

This is your code.
But i dont know how to make profile